# Angular $inject is causing service to fail

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Anytime I have a $inject in my service it is failing.  I cannot seem to find the error.  If I comment out the inject and the param on the constructor it works fine.

thanks

```
 module app.common {
 export interface IHelloService {
    sayHello(text: string): string;
    sayGoodbye(text: string): string
}
export class HelloService implements IHelloService {
   // lokiInst: Loki;
   // idbAdapter: LokiIndexedAdapter;
   // usersCollection: LokiCollection<starter.domain.User>;

    static $inject = ["$scope"];
    constructor(private $scope:ng.IScope) {

    }


    sayHello(text: string): string {
        return "hello" + text;
    };
    sayGoodbye(text: string): string {
        return "goodbye"+ text;
    };
}


angular.module("app.common", []);

angular
    .module("starter")
    .service("helloService",
    HelloService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't import `$scope` from a service. [See the docs on this point](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) -- only Controllers have access to this.

Depending on what you intend to do (this code doesn't *use* `$scope` so it's hard to guess), you can import `$rootScope` instead, or perhaps `Hello` ought to be a Controller rather than a Service.